# Rename files using math operations

Tags: bash, perl, batch-rename

I am trying to rename some files using a bash command, but I don't know how to add an arithmetic expression/math operation into the regex expression.

Input:

```
a000.png
a001.png
...
```

Ouput:

```
a010.png
a011.png
...
```

I am trying to add 10 to the names.

Some things I tried:

```
rename -n -e 's/a(\d+).png/a$1 + 10.png/' *
rename -n -e 's/a(\d+).png/a{$1 + 10}.png/' *
rename -n -e 's/a(\d+).png/a$($1 + 10).png/' *
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: The trick here is that the `rename` command uses `perl` syntax, rather than `bash` shell syntax. I don't have a good, comprehensive source on hand to elaborate/express this, but I will attach to my answer when I do.

Comment: I am hesitant to link to an external website; there are plenty of guides out there (a google search away). As a start, you can get a cursory overview using `man perlre`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, @TravisClarke. I'll keep this and your answer in mind for future reference, I do like the `rename` command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the trick. If you do not want the leading zero you can remove `sprintf` as well as the `"%03d"` format string. Furthermore, if the files to be renamed will **always** begin with `a`, you can also supplant the leading regex `[a-zA-Z]*` with the literal character `a`. Lastly, although the `*` file specifier may be adequate, I would recommend tacking on an extension as an additional safety precaution (e.g. `*.png`).

> As always, try it out first using the `-n` flag to verify the rename is *correct*.

```
rename -v 's/([a-zA-Z]*)([0-9]*)/$1.sprintf("%03d",$2+10)/e' *
```

Comment: For completeness, there is a *similar* (not duplicate) thread over on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47006/trying-to-do-arithmetic-in-perl-rename-tool-debian) which may shed additional light on the matter.

Comment: That worked, but if I have a lot of files, I get this error: "a001.png not renamed: a011.png already exists". I was able to rename everything to "bXXX.png' and then back to 'aXXX.png', but is there a simpler way?
I tought that sorting the names in reverse order would work  "ls | sort -r | rename ..." , but it didn't.

Comment: @klaus - I was wondering whether you'd run into that problem... Your `ls | sort -r` solution to reverse the order _does_ work, but you also have to remove the `*` from the end of the `rename` command because it only reads filenames from STDIN if no names are provided as arguments.

Comment: @DaveSherohman It works, but I tought that using `ls | sort -r` would solve the 'already exists' error in rename. But the solution was to use '-f' instead.

Comment: @klaus - Umm... If you "solved" it with `-f`, you might want to double-check your files and their contents. If you start with `a001`, `a011`, and `a021` and use `rename -f`, you will end up with only one file, `a031`, which will contain the original content of `a001`. `a011` and `a021` will be destroyed. I assume this is/was not your desired result.

Comment: @DaveSherohman Indeed, I tested here and `-f` does not work, and it would make me lose all files. It worked because for some reason I used `-f` together with `ls | sort -r`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `rename` to rename, you can still work with bash syntax. I had a bunch of old logs I needed to shift by 5 days, as in:

```
log.365.gz -> log.370.gz
log.364.gz -> log.369.gz
...
```

I used a for loop counting backwards:

```
for date in {365..1}; do
    mv -nv log.$date.gz log.$(date+5).gz
done
```

The `-n` flag moved the files without clobbering old files.